# How to bypass setting value to variable when one of the argument is undefined

Tags: javascript

How can I bypass setting value to variables inside the function, in a situation where only either one or two arguments gets sent into the function (instead of three).

Currently my code is like this:

```
var mj = function(x, y, z){
  if( x || y || z === !undefined){
    var xName = x.name;
    var yName = y.name; //throws error here
    var zName = z.name;
  }
}
mj({name: "mo"})
```

Comment: You mean other than `var xName = x && x.name; var yName = y && y.name;`?

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to this: `(x) || (y) || (z === true)` (`!undefined` is `true`)

Comment: @ raina77ow  only `var xName = x.name `. Not  this way: `var xName = x && x.name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use condition `(x && y && z)`, if either of these is undefined (which means all three are not passed) then the assignment code will not be executed.

```js
var mj = function(x, y, z) {
  if (x && y && z) {
    var xName = x.name;
    var yName = y.name; 
    var zName = z.name;
  }
}
mj({
  name: "mo"
})
```

**2nd Case**

In case you need only the once that are sent to be assigned then you may do:

```
var mj = function(x, y, z) {
    var xName = x && x.name;
    var yName = y && y.name; 
    var zName = z && z.name;
}
mj({
  name: "mo"
})
```

Note: in case a value is not passed you will **not get an error** but yes the xName, yName or zName will get undefined.